# Is it worthwhile to replace evaporator coil?

Tags: hvac, air-conditioning

My AC condenser is done for and needs to be replaced. The evaporator coil is 15 years old and still working. I could get both replaced at once, or just replace the AC condenser. Doing both will cost around $2300 more than doing just the condenser. Is it worthwhile to do both, or better to just do the condenser.

Another option might be to install a heat pump to replace both, but I'm not sure if that's how these things work. I'm a layman and don't know much about these topics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would replace a 15 year evap coil. Since the efficiency of the condenser/compressor has changed (more efficient), you also need to match it with the proper evap coil and metering device (TXV).

Comment: I agree.  Replacing major parts on a 15 year old system is not a good decision. Matched systems are much more efficient.